# Implementing NavigationView in android

Tags: java, android

i am working on a project and i happen to implement the "NavigationView" from the Google's Design Compat Library. But i ran into this problem where when an item is touched: i want it to change the activity.

So, what i am implying here is that can anyone give me the best solution of how i can implement this the right way like it is seen in the GMAIL app, where only the toolbar's title and the items in the List also changes.

I tried:

```
switch(menuItem.getitemId()){
menuItem.setChecked(true);

case R.id.navigation_item_1:
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Feeds.class));
```

But the result isn't what i wanted, Please can you help me.

Comment: These are the link which you can follow http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html and http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comportement you describe (i.e. keeping the actionbar and other stuff), take advantage of fragments and not activities : each time an action is clicked, the displayed fragment is changed, but the activity is still the same one.

Comment: Thanks but, if you could explain using a basic example..because i happen to be a begineer.

Comment: To change the fragment displayed on a screen, you must use the `FragmentManager` class. I suggest you read this presentation by Corey Latislaw that explains a lot about fragments https://prezi.com/qq6xlpg1vad7/the-fragment-transition-workshop/   I think this is a good start for beginners.